# Javascript: How to iterate array properly

Tags: javascript

I have a rather simple question. I have an array of objects, I dont think the structure of the object actually matters in this case, but I will provide it anyways:

I want to iterate the array, and check if the **`userId`** is the same as some variable value I have. If so I want to execute some logic, and then break the loop. But if not, I want to go to the next obj. However, if it's the end of the array, I want to execute some different logic.

**How can I achieve this?**

Like this:

```
let someUserValue = "123"

for (obj of arrayName) {
  if(someUserValue == Object.keys(obj)[0]) {
    // do somethin here and then stop iterating

    break
  } else {
    // go to the next obj in the array, but if the entire array has been searched, and no match was found
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Structure of Object:

```
  {
    [userId]: [
      {
        //postIdentifier: [userId + time],
        postIdentifier: [userId + time],
        time: [time],
        msg: form_data.get("message"),
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Take a look at `some()`

Comment: There's also: `.find()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ES6 you now have the `Array.find` function, it will return the first element found matching the predicate, else undefined.

```
const result = someArray.find((element) => element.userId == someUserValue);
if(result)
//do something with it
else
//do something if not found
```

[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Will this return the object containing that value? or what will it exactly return, because I need the object

Comment: @Nick Yes, it will return the first object found which has a matching `userId` property value, please see the link to the documentation I provided. Else it returns undefined, hence the `if(result)` in my answer. As undefined is a falsy value: [falsy-values-in-javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the link you provided. But Im still confused about something. Can find also be used when you are searching for the key and not the value? if so how?

Comment: @Nick So you want to see if the object has the property of `userId`?? If so, you can look at [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)